# Symfony app suddenly down because of /var/cache/prod/pools/ folder permission issue

Tags: docker, caching, symfony4

My Dockerized Symfony4 app was up since 2 months, suddenly it stopped working this morning, with no hints in log

I've tried to rebuild the container and got this message :

```
chmod: cannot access 'var/cache/prod/pools/vxeRd2PSFn/5fbf647725b467.33862000': No such file or directory
```

So I've  entered the container and ran this :

```
root@eff6089c776e:/app# chmod -R 777 var/cache/
```

Then the app worked fine !

I don't get it : what was the problem ? a permission issue of the var/cache folder ? how is this possible ? how can I prevent this ?

PS : sometimes I have a similar problem with var/prod/**sessions** folder : the build process can't overwrite the folder, when I list files I can see two owners : www-data and root ! I don't understand why do I have files with different owners in the same folder !

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the answer but sadly enough I don’t have command rights because I’ve less than 50 reputation. I suggest you add a tag with your webserver because it’s related to that heavily this question.

You maybe can check if the owner of your parent folder “var” is maybe root and if you set it to www-data it could work maybe no guarantees.

For further explanation the var folder is for saving sessions and cache most of the time so editing the owner is not impactful as far as I know but I’m no expert. Maybe changing the var folder permission could also help instead of the var/cache.